# Solaris 10 top more free memory than real

Tags: solaris, top, solaris-10

When I type TOP command in my server I get result:

```
CPU states: 79.3% idle,  9.2% user, 11.6% kernel,  0.0% iowait,  0.0% swap
Memory: 16G real, 19G free, 283G swap in use, 115G swap free
```

I don't have free command as well as /etc/meminfo file. My question is what can cause bigger value of Free memory than real is?

Comment: And what makes you think that this isn't the "real" value ? What source of "real" value do you use, since you didn't explain it ?

Comment: Presumably they are referring to the "16G real" in the top output.

Comment: Yes, 16G real output from top.

Comment: Don't use `top` on Solaris to determine memory usage.  See http://www.unix.com/solaris/140519-top-output-swap-output-differing.html, http://www.unix.com/solaris/136240-free-memory-top-prstat-command.html, and http://www.unix.com/solaris/143354-help-memory-usage-solaris-ps-efl-top.html for multiple examples why.  You can use `vmstat` or `echo ::memstat | mdb -k` as root.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris has different attitude  in representing memory,
I strongly encourage you use below instruction to get Mem info

```
# echo ::memstat | mdb -k
Page Summary                Pages                MB  %Tot
------------     ----------------  ----------------  ----
Kernel                       7308                57   23%
Anon                         9055                70   29%
Exec and libs                1968                15    6%
Page cache                   2224                17    7%
Free (cachelist)             6470                50   20%
Free (freelist)              4641                36   15%

Total                       31666               247
Physical                    31256               244
```